# Url_Key & Store_Id (Attribute Already Exists)

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1.8, ee-1.13

When we create or modify a product -- the `url_key` doesn't seem to associate with the `store_id` of the product. For example:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prodid);
$product->setUrlKey('product-url-key')
$product->setStoreId(1); 
$product->save();
```

**But here lies the problem:**

I would expect `url_key` in the Table `catalog_product_entity_url_key` to have a store_id of 1, but it gets set to 0. How else should a product be saved to that the url_key gets the proper store_id?

[image]

**Background on this problem:**

We are writing scripts for updating programs and have been getting a lot of these errors:

```
Uncaught exception 'Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Exception' with message 'Product with the 'product-url-key-added' url_key attribute already exists.' in /var/www/mage02/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:1348
```

Looking further into the code, this problem seems to be created because of how the store_id is getting set. We can make the problem go away by manually updating the store_id.. however, on the re-save -- the store_id for the url_key gets set back to 0.

**Magento Version used:** 1.13.1.0 (Fresh Install)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting the store id before loading the product. Something like this:
`$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(1)->load($prodId);`

Comment: Marius. Its still hard to determine the issue but I think you're on to something. I did go through the code and explicitly `setStoreId()` and the issues I was having became less frequent. This issue seems to be primarily related to EE 1.13.1.0 and doesn't exist in EE 1.13.0.2 or CE 1.8. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you found a permanent solution for 1.13.1.0?

Comment: Any solutions to this on 1.13.1.0?

Comment: A better solution is: `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);`

Comment: Thanks! Setting the current store to the admin store solved the problem for me why importing products from the CLI wasn't working!

Answer (score 11):

Researching what B00MER and Marius where saying, it appears that in EE 13.1+ the offending function is _isAvailableUrl in app/code/core/Enterprise/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Urlkey.php

There is a comment in li 179:180

```
179         // we should allow save same url key for product in current store view
180         // but not allow save existing url key in current store view from another store view
```

However, the select statement right before this reads:

```
173         $select = $this->_connection->select()
174             ->from($this->getAttribute()->getBackendTable(), array('entity_id', 'store_id'))
175             ->where('value = ?', $object->getUrlKey())
176             ->limit(1);
177         $row = $this->_connection->fetchRow($select);
```

This select statement just queries all records of catalog_product_entity_url_key and doesn't take account the current store id. So I modified the file like so which takes into account the current store id of the record being saved. This appears to fix the issue.

```
diff --git a/app/code/core/Enterprise/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Urlkey.php b/app/code/core/Enterprise/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Urlkey.php index 3ad4bea..c4319bd 100644
--- a/app/code/core/Enterprise/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Urlkey.php
+++ b/app/code/core/Enterprise/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Urlkey.php
@@ -173,6 +173,7 @@ class Enterprise_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Urlkey
         $select = $this->_connection->select()
             ->from($this->getAttribute()->getBackendTable(), array('entity_id', 'store_id'))
             ->where('value = ?', $object->getUrlKey())
+            ->where('store_id = ?', $object->getStoreId())
             ->limit(1);
         $row = $this->_connection->fetchRow($select);
```

Comment: Thanks, I got same issue in Magento EE 1.14 + and issue resolved