# How to load and save product in EE 1.13

Tags: product, magento-enterprise, ee-1.13

In previous versions of Magento, I was able to use this code:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(147);
$product->setDescription('test description');
$product->save();
```

However, in EE 1.13.1, I am getting a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Exception' with message 'Product with
>   the 'louis-vuitton-handbag' url_key attribute already exists.' in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magentoee113/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:1348
>   ....

If I set the store ID when loading the product, then it works:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(0)->load(147);
$product->setDescription('test description');
$product->save();
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

To save prices per website/store and to avoid getting the 'url_key' error do the following:

```
foreach ($storeIds as $storeId) {
    //load the product with store id
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->load($productId);

    //Set the store price
    $product->setPrice($price);

    //To stop Magento regenerating url-key for store, set following,
    $product->setUrlKey(false);

    //Save the product
    $product->save();
}
```

This has been tested and it works.

Comment: Wow, there is no way I would know to use `setURLKey(false)`.

Answer (score 4):

(Possible Assumption) Adding the setStoreId appears to be required now in 1.13.1.0

Comment: I think you are wrong. You have to set the store_id if you want to save or load storeview specific content. If you want to get website scoped content or default, then you don't need this.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12500/url-key-store-id-attribute-already-exists This problem, leads me to believe my assumption.

Comment: Interesting magento bug - I think. Thanks for the link. The problem is, magento tries to save everything in store view scope (because you are in frontend?) but the url_key already exists and magento doesn't realize it is the same product? whatever. If it solves the problem I'll be quiet.

Answer (score 0):

There is official magento patch to fix that. This is a bug.

Comment: Can you provide more details about this?

Comment: Sounds like a EE bugfix, which you are not allowed to publish. But if this fix is part of CE 1.8.1 one could extract it and post it here...